# Changing the Enter Button to Say Guess

Tags: java, android, button, keyboard, enter

I'm making a guessing game app where you have to guess a number between 1 and 100. The numeric keyboard has an enter button, I want the function enter to stay the same but instead of saying enter, I want it to say Guess. I'm told I have to change this in my onCreate() method and not the xml file. Any ideas on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: are you try to change the text on soft keyboard ??

Comment: i think you can't change the keyboard  text , but there is another solution you can create slide view that take same key board animation and put the keys with the name you need

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it as follows, but it may not work on all devices as vendors can create their own custom keyboards

```
  EditText input = new EditText(context);
  input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
  input.setImeActionLabel("Guess", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Alternatively you might need to do it in the XML, but the same limitations will probably apply

```
  android:imeActionLabel="Guess"
```

Comment: that just changed the enter button to say Done and when clicked nothing happens

Comment: I've tried that and it changes the button to say Guess, but when clicked it doesn't do anything except hide the keyboard

Comment: @DavidGray What did you expect to happen? You have to add an onEditorActionListener to catch the event.

Comment: Have you actually experimented yourself with some other combinations? Try using IME_ACTION_GO instead of DONE, does that make it do what you expect?

Comment: What kcoppock will definitely work if you can't get it to work by experimenting with the Ime options alone. If somebody gives you an answer that at least points you in the right direction you need to experiment along the lines they've suggested before just saying it doesn't work

Comment: I had a simple error with my onEditorActionListener that I finally caught. Thanks guys

Comment: If my answer has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you